# Transition animator works in Activity but not fragment

Tags: android, animation, fragment, transition, animator

I've been trying to follow the android [flip card tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html). As instructed, I created four custom animator sets

card_flip_right_in.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="0" />

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="180"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="300" />

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="150"
    android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

card_flip_right_out.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-180"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="300" />

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="150"
    android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

card_flip_left_in.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="0" />

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="-180"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="300" />

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="150"
    android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

card_flip_left_out.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="180"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="300" />

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="150"
    android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

And, I have this in my fragment:

```
public class ContestantInfoFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context context;

    private String cName, cCountry, cDesc;

    private TextView contestant_name, contestant_country, contestant_desc;
    private ImageButton flip_btn;

    public ContestantInfoFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contestant_info, container, false);

        context = inflater.getContext();

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle != null) {
            cName = bundle.getString("NAME", "Problem loading contestant's name");
            cCountry = bundle.getString("COUNTRY", "Problem loading contestant's country");
            cDesc = bundle.getString("DESC", "Problem loading contestant's description");

            contestant_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contestant_name);
            contestant_country = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contestant_country);
            contestant_desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contestant_desc);

            contestant_name.setText(cName);
            contestant_country.setText(cCountry);
            contestant_desc.setText(cDesc);
        }

        flip_btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.contestant_flip_btn);
        flip_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                                             R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
                        .replace(R.id.mainContent, new ContestantsFragment())
                                        .addToBackStack(null)
                                        .commit();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

However, I got syntax errors (red zip lines) for using

```
.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                                         R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
```

The feedback I got was "Expected resource of type anim"
I did realize if I did inside of an activity, the error warning would go away, but not when I implement in a fragment.
Anyone has any idea why this is not working? And how do I make it work in a fragment?

Comment: Support library only works with `anim`